# How to sort within array separated by Key with comma separated value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to sort withins single array separated by Key as date with comma separated value.

The legacy Timeseries is sending data in the below format

```
arr1 = ['3/13/20,2179','3/14/20,2727', '3/14/20,1024' , '3/14/20,3020', '3/13/20,100', '3/13/20,190']
```

I'm struggling to sort it on below format the key is the date grouped by all the required values

```
arr1 = [3/13/20,2179,100,190,3/14/20,2727,1024,3020]
```

Any pointer/hint will be helpful.

Comment: order ? of the sorting, on date ??

Comment: Have you tried anything? It has to be within the array? Or you can allocate more? Something like this should take advantage of creating a map with the array where the dates are the keys and their value is an array of the values for each date.

Comment: please add a valid result.

Comment: @xdeepakv, check the Nina Answer

Comment: @anish I checked ur result and updated solution. if u still want can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the first part and get a flat stringed result.

```js
var data = ['3/13/20,2179', '3/14/20,2727', '3/14/20,1024', '3/14/20,3020', '3/13/20,100', '3/13/20,190'],
    result = Object
        .entries(data.reduce((r, s) => {
            const [date, value] = s.split(',');
            r[date] = r[date] || [];
            r[date].push(value);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .flat(2);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is very close to my Solution

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the date, `split key` to get `date` and `count`. Split `date-string`, if you want to sort on the date. and return diff of compare in sort callback function.

**Sort based on date and then count**

```js
arr1 = [
  "3/13/20,2179",
  "3/14/20,2727",
  "3/14/20,1024",
  "3/14/20,3020",
  "3/13/20,100",
  "3/13/20,190",
];
const sort = (data) => {
  return data.sort((x, y) => {
    const [mm, dd, yy, num] = x.split(/[/,]/);
    const [mm1, dd1, yy1, num1] = y.split(/[/,]/);
    const d1 = new Date(dd, mm, yy).getTime();
    const d2 = new Date(dd1, mm1, yy1).getTime();
    if (d1 !== d1) return d1 - d2;
    return Number(num) - Number(num1);
  });
};
console.log(sort(arr1));
```

**Updated: groupBy date**

```js
arr1 = [
  "3/13/20,2179",
  "3/14/20,2727",
  "3/14/20,1024",
  "3/14/20,3020",
  "3/13/20,100",
  "3/13/20,190",
];
const group = (data) => {
  const mapped = data.reduce((map, item) => {
    const [date, num] = item.split(",");
    if (!map[date]) map[date] = [];
    !map[date].push(num);
    return map;
  }, {});
  let result = [];
  for (const key in mapped) {
    const element = mapped[key];
    result = result.concat(key).concat(element);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(group(arr1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, the second solution is very close to my Question

Comment: @anish i updated groupby solution, please check. this is optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This also help

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [
  '3/13/20,2179',
  '3/14/20,2727',
  '3/14/20,1024',
  '3/14/20,3020',
  '3/13/20,100',
  '3/13/20,190',
];

const groupValuesByDate = (datesDictionary, dateWithValue) => {
  const [date, value] = dateWithValue.split(',');

  return {
    ...datesDictionary,
    [date]: datesDictionary[date] ? [...datesDictionary[date], parseInt(value, 10)] : [parseInt(value, 10)],
  };
};

const valuesGroupedByDate = arr1.reduce(groupValuesByDate, {});

let formattedDates = [];

for (date in valuesGroupedByDate) {
  const values = valuesGroupedByDate[date];
  formattedDates = [...formattedDates, date, ...values];
}

console.log(formattedDates);
```